# MKMapItem.forCurrentLocation() returns "Unknown Location"

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, core-location

Inside my `ViewController's` class `viewDidLoad` method I have:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    requestAuthorization()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    print(MKMapItem.forCurrentLocation())
}
```

and here is `requestAuthorization()` function:

```
private func requestAuthorization(){
    if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .notDetermined{
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
    else if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .denied{
        //TODO
    }

}
```

the problem is that `forCurrentLocation()` function never returns actual user location instead returned coordinates of MKMapItem are: (latitude: 0, longitude: 0). Here is the result of the print function.

> MKMapItem: 0x60000014e020 
>       isCurrentLocation = 1;
>       name = "Unknown Location";

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**

The reason I wanted to use `MKMapItem.forCurrentLocation()` was that I planned to get user coordinates in `prepareForSegue`. And I thought it would be easier than using `didUpdateLocations` delegate method. See the code:

```
if segue.identifier == "categories",
        let destinationVC = segue.destination as? CategoriesGroupViewController{
        if let cell = sender as? UICollectionViewCell{
            let indexPath = categoriesCollectionView.indexPath(for: cell)
            destinationVC.groupOfDestinations = destinationsByCategory[indexPath!.row]
            // 0 is index for Near Me cell
            if indexPath?.row == 0 {
                destinationVC.groupOfDestinations = getNearMeDestinations()
            }

 }

private func getNearMeDestinations() -> GroupOfDestinations{
        let userCoordinates = MKMapItem.forCurrentLocation().placemark.coordinate
        let nearMeCircularRegion: CLCircularRegion = CLCircularRegion(center: userCoordinates, radius: 10000, identifier: "nearMe")
...

        return nearMeDestinations
    }
```

Comment: Use `print(mapView.userLocation.location?.coordinate)` if you have MKMapView inside ViewController.

Answer (score 2):

You´re not doing anything wrong. The `MKMapItem.forCurrentLocation()` Creates and returns a singleton map item object representing the device’s current location.

`MKMapItem.forCurrentLocation().isCurrentLocation` is a Boolean value indicating whether the map item represents the user’s current location. In your case `true`.

`MKMapItem.forCurrentLocation().name` The descriptive name associated with the map item. If this map item represents the user’s current location, the value in property is set to a localized version of “Current Location”.

And that it returns *Unknown Location* is weird. But it´s enough for you to keep track of the `MKMapItem.forCurrentLocation().isCurrentLocation` value.

**Update:**
To get the user locations coordinate do the following:

```
var location = CLLocation()

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    guard let latitude = manager.location?.coordinate.latitude, let longitude = manager.location?.coordinate.longitude else { return }
    location = CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
}
```

And then use location which always will be up to date when the user moves.

Comment: Thank you for response it clarified a bit, but see my edit, the coordinates of MKMapItem are always (latitude: 0, longitude: 0) even if location manager delegate returns actual user location.

Comment: @barola_mes, don´t use `MKMapItem` to get the user location. Checkout my edit of how to do it instead.

Comment: please see my edit, I was not explicit at the first time

Comment: @barola_mes, the `location` variable represents the users location. You can use it, try it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
```

> Put above line outside if else block, Like

```
 var locationManager: CLLocationManager?

 private func requestAuthorization(){

    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.delegate = self

    if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .notDetermined{
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
    else if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .denied{
        //TODO
    }
}
```

There is delegate method for map, Which gives you current location

```
// CLLocationManagerDelegate
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    guard let location = locations.last else {
        return
    }
    Print(location)// This is your current location
}
```